# Find value between some symbol

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, find

I have values between this some symbol (`<>`). I need to write a query that will extract them.

For example, given the following:

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(MAX) = N'(<1002>+<1003>+<1004>+<1048>+<1049>+<1050>)/(<1400>*2)'
```

I’d like to extract the following values into a table:

```
table 
1002
1003
1004
1048
1049
1050
1400
```

Comment: What's the version of SQL Server?

Comment: sql server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be really easy to do this if you implement SQL CLR regex functions, but if you have not the time or skill you can use something like this:

```
DECLARE @a VARCHAR(MAX) = N'(<1002>+<1003>+<1004>+<1048>+<1049>+<1050>)/(<1400>*2)'

SET @A = REPLACE(@A, '<', 'lt;');
SET @A = REPLACE(@A, '>', 'gt;');

DECLARE @xml XML

SET @xml = '<node>' + REPLACE(@A, 'gt;', '</node><node>') + '</node>'


SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.c)
      ,SUBSTRING(T.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'), CHARINDEX('lt;', T.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')) + 3, 1024)
FROM @xml.nodes('node') T(c)
WHERE CHARINDEX('lt;', T.c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')) >0;
```

[image]

Comment: gotqn, this can be put a bit simpler ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This can be put a bit simpler:

```sql
DECLARE @yourStr VARCHAR(MAX) = N'(<1002>+<1003>+<1004>+<1048>+<1049>+<1050>)/(<1400>*2)';

SELECT AllX.value('@z','int')
FROM (VALUES (CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(@yourStr,'<','<x z="'),'>','" />') AS XML))) A(Casted)
CROSS APPLY A.Casted.nodes('/x') B(AllX);
```

That's it :-)

The idea in short:

By replacing the `<` and the `>` we can create a (not well-formed) XML like this:

```
(<x z="1002" />+<x z="1003" />+<x z="1004" />+<x z="1048" />+<x z="1049" />+<x z="1050" />)/(<x z="1400" />*2)
```

T-SQL can deal with *fragments*, so we can use `.nodes('/x')` to read all `<x>` elements in the root level. Any other content is just *noise* between the elements, floating around in `text()` nodes we can ignore.

We just read the `z`-attribute and return it as `int`.

Comment: That's nice. I did not push myself too much doing the answer - just trying to solve the issue, but this is better way using the XML functions for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want via working with [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function for removing any unneeded chars, then execute the statement via using [SP_EXECUTESQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) as next:-

```
Create table #TempTable (col1 int)

DECLARE @a VARCHAR(MAX) = N'(<1002>+<1003>+<1004>+<1048>+<1049>+<1050>)/(<1400>*2)'

Declare @SqlStatement  NVARCHAR(MAX) =  'Insert into #TempTable Values ' + 

REPLACE(Replace(REPLACE(REPLACE(Replace(REPLACE(@a,'<',''),'>',''),'/(','+'),')+','+'),'*2',''),'+','),(')

Exec sp_executesql @SqlStatement 

Select * from #TempTable

Drop table #TempTable
```

**Result:-**

```
col1
1002
1003
1004
1048
1049
1050
1400
```